# How to implement a proxy pool into multiple scrapy crawlers?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

I have to implement a proxy pool in a server that has multiple crawlers that use scrapy.

How would I implement a proxy pool given that I already have a DB with multiple proxies that are been updated all time.

I don't want to add the proxies directly in the code, mainly because a lot of those proxies die really fast and some of the crawlers take too long to finish.

Is there a way to implement this using a middleware or something that would not require to change every crawler I got ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement such a proxy handling using a [downloader middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html).

[Search Github for ‘scrapy proxy’](https://github.com/search?q=scrapy%20proxy) to find some examples of downloader middlewares that handle proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

middlewares

```
import requests
PROXY_POOL_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/random'
class RandomProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        proxy_ip = requests.get(PROXY_POOL_URL).text

        request.meta["proxy"] = 'http://' + proxy_ip
```

and settings

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddlware': 543,
}
```